# I don't know why my code is working without using arraylist in java

Tags: java

*This code is working correctly but i havn't used arraylist but it is working properly. Can anyone answer it?*

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
class findMinMax{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer[] arr2 = {2,1,35,-6,-2,6,9};
        int mymin = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(arr2));
        int mymax = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(arr2));
        System.out.println(mymin);
        System.out.println(mymax);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays.asList returns a immutable ArrayList

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian It's not immutable, it's just not resizable. Changes to the list returned by Arrays.asList write thru to the original array.

Comment: It is working because is is algorithmically correct.  There is nothing mysterious about that.  I assume that you are *required* to use an `ArrayList` for some reason.  And you are *actually* asking how to do that.  Hint: look at the constructors for `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.asList takes Array as input and returns a new ArrayList with elements of array as its element and returned ArrayList is not resizable

Comment: It's not immutable, it's just not resizable. Changes to the list returned by Arrays.asList write thru to the original array.

Comment: Agree it is not immutable as reference used can still be mutated.Have edited the comments